# How to turn off or uninstall lshell?

Tags: linux, shell

We have read the Readme.md file of LShell and browsed through their [Github issues](https://github.com/ghantoos/lshell/issues) but did not find our solution.

We initially installed LSHELL with what they described in their [Github installation instructions](https://github.com/ghantoos/lshell#installation):

```
python setup.py install --no-compile --install-scripts=/usr/bin/
```

Now LSHELL is turned on by default for root user.

1. How do we turn it off and on at will?
2. How do we uninstall it? We have tried to uninstall with command:

   `apt-get purge ishell`

but we got response:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package lshell
E: Could not read response to hello message from hook [ ! -f /usr/bin/snap ] || /usr/bin/snap advise-snap --from-apt 2>/dev/null || true: Success
E: Sub-process [ ! -f /usr/bin/snap ] || /usr/bin/snap advise-snap --from-apt 2>/dev/null || true returned an error code (100)
E: Failure running hook [ ! -f /usr/bin/snap ] || /usr/bin/snap advise-snap --from-apt 2>/dev/null || true
```

Comment: Did you read the first comment in the Issues section of the Github Page? Because your root account is in the limited lshell with no `sudo`, you need to go into Recovery Mode/Emergency Mode and use `chsh -s /usr/bin/bash root`. The method that you used doesn't change the shell to `lshell` by default for anyone. Some used the command above with `/usr/bin/lshell` to set it that way. Remember that it is a limited shell and is best used for regular user accounts and not `root`.